# Adding a custom plugin to each page without actually embedding into the page

Tags: php, jquery, html, jsp

I have a online chat plugin using jQuery and HTML. My website has to many pages, I want to include this chat plugin to each page without actually changing other pages. How can I perform this?

[without actually changing other pages]Basically my requirement is to add/include chat plugin on each page.
Or if they hit the website for the first time it should show in the browser and it should continue to show until user actually close that. I am ok for any suggestion from using server languages like JSP, PHP.